Optimal Value t for Subdivision of Cubic Bézier Curve and How to Calculate It
In Gabriel Suchowolski’s paper, “Quadratic bezier offsetting with selective subdivision”, he explains how the midpoint—or better said, a parameter $t$ of 0.5—is often not the optimal* point on a quadratic Bézier curve for subdividing it into two new quadratic Bézier curves, and he instead describes a point $P_t$ on the curve that has the minimum Euclidean distance to the control point $P_1$ of any quadratic Bézier curve that is optimal for subdivision, and he then provides a method for calculating the parameter $t$ at this point.
However, I am working exclusively with cubic Bézier curves, and so I was wondering if there were an analogous optimal parameter $t$ for subdivision of Bézier curves of that degree, and if so, how to go about calculating it.
I tried to find the answer to this question by browsing the literature on this topic, but was unable to find anything specifically, although my search was, no doubt, non-exhaustive, because I had difficulty phrasing search terms without turning up dozens of tangentially-related (no pun intended) or otherwise adjacent issues.
My intuition is that, since in the quadratic case, the optimal parameter for subdivision is closest in terms of Euclidean distance to the single control point of Bézier curves of that degree, in the case of cubic Bézier curves, the optimal point for subdivision on a cubic Bézier curve may be determined in an analogous way by calculating the parameter that is either closest in terms of Euclidean distance to the line connecting a cubic Bézier curve’s two control points $P_1$ and $P_2$ or the parameter at which the first derivative of the cubic Bézier curve (i.e. the tangent at that parameter) is equal to the slope of the line connecting its two control points.  Also, in the case of cubic Bézier curves this is complicated by the fact that, depending on how a curve’s control points are configured, that curve may have an inflection point, and the line connecting its two control points may thus intersect the curve itself.  It was also my intuition that in these cases, the optimal parameter for subdivision on the curve would coincide with the point of intersection of the line connecting its two control points and the curve (obviously the point of minimum distance even if the curve can never be tangent to the line connecting the two control points in this case).  I also had a hunch that this point of intersection may also coincide with the point of inflection on such an “S-shaped” cubic Bézier curve.
So, again, my question is firstly, whether these intuitions are correct, and if not, what, if any, is the optimal parameter $t$ for subdivision on a cubic Bézier curve, in a manner analogous to Suchowolski’s method for optimizing subdivision of a quadratic Bézier curve, and secondly, how to calculate the optimal parameter $t$ for subdivision on a cubic Bézier curve, however it is defined.

(*) Note: optimal, as used in my post, is defined in the manner discussed in the Suchowolski paper provided at the start of the post, i.e. the optimal value $t$ is the value $t$ that allows for the fewest number of recursive iterations of subdivision (De Casteljau method) and the best (closest/most accurate) result when drawing an offset curve of the given the cubic Bézier curve.

Not clear to me what “optimal” means. What are we trying to optimize?

@bubba I am using it in the sense of of the Suchowolski paper provided at the start of the post, which means the value $t$ which allows for the fewest number of repeated subdivisions and best (closest/most accurate) results when drawing an offset curve for the cubic bézier.  Sorry, I'll add this note to the OP as well.
